# Combo Box Update in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on combo box, i am refresh the combo box values , first i am deleting all values and then re populating it. But it is not working. The code duplicates the values in combo box which is creating problem. Here is my Code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < updateCombo.Items.Count; i++)
    updateCombo.Items.RemoveAt(i);

    //----------- Now Adding New Values --------
    updateCombo.Items.Add("Select an option . . .");

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Queries.qry9, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Kindly please help me in fixing this problem.

Comment: are you sure the query does not return duplicate entries? use updateCombo.Items.Clear to cler all items at once

Comment: If you had 10 items and have removed five of them, leaving 5 items left, what happens when you request to delete the 6th of them?

Comment: No error in combo box clearing, Every thing is ok. Query is just selecting in ascending order. Still i am getting duplicate items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why this would happen- but if Items.Count comes back as 0 then your loop won't remove any of the existing contents from the items list and you'll get duplicates.

have you tried just clearing all the contents of the list regardless using:

```
updateCombo.Items.Clear();
```

It saves you having to iterate through them all, removing them one by one anyway.

Comment: It worked.. I wonder what the original code is behind the clear function... dOES any body know? Still its the right answer. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is deleting the item at 0, then at 1, then at 2, and so on.
However, when the item at 0 is deleted, that position in the list doesn't remain empty - the other items effectively shift down by one.

So, if you changed your clearing code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < updateCombo.Items.Count; i++)
updateCombo.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

it should work.
However, as others have suggested, using `updateCombo.Items.Clear();` is a better approach.

Comment: Great Answer, its just like table value deletion in java. Thanx Jon. Now I am clear.